# How to retrieve value of a ui:param in the backing bean of same page

Tags: java, jsf-2, facelets, composite-component

i want to retrieve the value of ui:param in my backing bean but from same page not while navigating from page to page
i tried :

```
FaceletContext faceletContext = (FaceletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getAttributes().get(FaceletContext.FACELET_CONTEXT_KEY);
String formId = (String) faceletContext.getAttribute("formId");
```

and it returned null also i tried :

```
String param = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
            .getRequestParameterMap().get(name);
```

also it returned null
i tried getting these valies in preRenderView and in a postValidate event and in two ways returning null 
don't forget i want to get the value of a ui:param of the page i am in

Comment: try f:param insted of ui:param.

Comment: i tried it also returned null

Comment: I came across this question when I had the same problem. For me, it turned out that the error message was a bit misleading. It wasn't actually the `<ui:param>` object reference which was `null`, but the method on that object was not declared on the interface which I was using. My advice would be to set breakpoints on the object that "value" refers to in your UI parameter and check that *it* really *is* `null`

Answer (score -1):

The problem i suppose is very similar to the one i'm also facing.
Allow me to throw some light on this problem.

This problem i faced when there are two "ui:include" wrapped under "p:dialog"..
something like this

```
<p:dialog header="Customer Selection Criteria" widgetVar="customerSelectionDialog" width="1200" position="center" appendToBody="true">
        <h:form id="customerForm">
            <p:outputPanel id="customerSelection">
                <ui:include src="../INTERNAL/8500.xhtml">
                    <ui:param name="showCidSelect" value="1" /> 
                    <ui:param name="targetObject" value="#{customerDetailsInquiry.cf8444.cg1014.cg1014cidnumb}" />
                </ui:include>
                <p:commandButton rendered="false" value="#{COMMON.COMMON_SELECTBUTTON}" action="#{customerDetailsInquiry.tchelp.handleReturnFromCustomerSelectionCriteria}" oncomplete="customerSelectionDialog.hide();" update=":mainForm:cf8444icg1014c1002" >
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{customerSearchEngine}" target="#{flash.customerSearchEngine}"/>
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:outputPanel>
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
    <p:dialog closeOnEscape="true" modal="true" appendToBody="false" header="Entity Stack" widgetVar="entityStackDialog" width="400" >
        <h:form id="entityForm">
            <ui:include src="../INTERNAL/StackedEntity.xhtml">
                <ui:param name="displayCaption" value="CID Numbers" />

                <ui:param name="department" value="8" /> 
                <ui:param name="stackedObject" value="#{customerDetailsInquiry.cf8444.cg1014.cg1014cidnumb}" />
            </ui:include>

        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
```

Now when i try to launch 8500.xhtml my showCidSelect param value returns "null" always.
This works fine if i replace the code as follows

```
<p:dialog header="Customer Selection Criteria" widgetVar="customerSelectionDialog" width="1200" position="center" appendToBody="true">
        <h:form id="customerForm">
            <p:outputPanel id="customerSelection">
                <ui:include src="../INTERNAL/8500.xhtml">
                    <ui:param name="showCidSelect" value="1" /> 
                    <ui:param name="targetObject" value="#{customerDetailsInquiry.cf8444.cg1014.cg1014cidnumb}" />
                </ui:include>
                <p:commandButton rendered="false" value="#{COMMON.COMMON_SELECTBUTTON}" action="#{customerDetailsInquiry.tchelp.handleReturnFromCustomerSelectionCriteria}" oncomplete="customerSelectionDialog.hide();" update=":mainForm:cf8444icg1014c1002" >
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{customerSearchEngine}" target="#{flash.customerSearchEngine}"/>
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:outputPanel>
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
    <p:dialog closeOnEscape="true" modal="true" appendToBody="false" header="Entity Stack" widgetVar="entityStackDialog" width="400" >
        <h:form id="entityForm">
            <ui:include src="../INTERNAL/StackedEntity.xhtml">
                <ui:param name="displayCaption" value="CID Numbers" />
                <ui:param name="showCidSelect" value="1" />
                <ui:param name="department" value="8" /> 
                <ui:param name="stackedObject" value="#{customerDetailsInquiry.cf8444.cg1014.cg1014cidnumb}" />
            </ui:include>

        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
```

I had to explicitly pass showCidSelect for both "ui:include" to make it work.

May be this is the same problem you are also facing?
Post some sample code of UI.